# Can objects get lost if a LinkedList is add/remove fast by lots of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

sound like a silly question. I just started Java Concurrency.

I have a LinkedList that acts as a task queue and is accessed by multiple threads. They removeFirst() and execute it, other threads put more tasks (.add()). Tasks can have the thread put them back to the queue.

I notice that when there are a lot of tasks and they are put back to the queue a lot, the number of tasks I add to the queue initially are not what come out, 1, or sometimes 2 is missing.

I checked everything and I *synchronized every critical section + notifyAll().*

Already mark the LinkedList as 'volatile'.

Exact number is 384 tasks, each is put back 3072 times.

The problem doesn't occur if there is a small number of tasks & put back. Also if I System.out.println() all the steps then it doesn't happens anymore so I can't debug.

Could it be possible that LinkedList.add() is not fast enough so the threads somehow miss it?

**Simplified code:**

```
public void callByAllThreads() {     
      Task executedTask = null;
      do 
      {
        // access by multiple thread
      synchronized(asyncQueue) {
          executedTask = asyncQueue.poll();
          if(executedTask == null) {
          inProcessCount.incrementAndGet(); // mark that there is some processing going on
        } 
      }

      if(executedTask != null) {
        executedTask.callMethod(); // subclass of task can override this method
        synchronized(asyncQueue) {
          inProcessCount.decrementAndGet();
          asyncQueue.notifyAll();
        }
      }
      }
      while(executedTask != null);
}
```

The Task can override callMethod:

```
public void callMethodOverride() {
  synchronized(getAsyncQueue()) {
    getAsyncQueue().add(this);
    getAsyncQueue().notifyAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is that you should select a data structure from [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) so that it is thread-safe. The standard `LinkedList` is not.  Ether `BlockingQueue` or `BlockingDequeue` sound like they'd fit the bill.

Comment: The idea that `linkedList.add(...)` is not fast enough makes no sense.  A single thread can only do one thing at a time.  If thread A calls add(), then it won't do anything else until the add() returns  It doesn't matter how long that takes.  The only question is, will your program allow any other thread to access the same LinkedList at the same time?  If it does, even if the other thread only _looks_ at the list) then that's likely will cause problems.

Comment: P.S., `volatile` may not mean what you think it means.  A LinkedList can never be volatile.  If you write `volatile LinkedList list;` that makes the _variable_ volatile, not the LinkedList object.  It won't have any effect on what happens when you call `list.add()` or `list.removeFirst()` or any other method.  The only time `volatile` makes a difference is when you _update_ the variable (e.g., `list = new LinkedList();`

Comment: James, your comment is so eye-opening! I didn't know that to search for it to begin with! Only learn about volatile a couple of days ago. I suspect thread-cached is the issue here because I encounter that with another boolean variable a couple of days back, but I didn't know about what you said regarding volatile reference type. Let me try some solution. Will get back to you soon

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs for LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

i.e. you should synchronize access to the list. You say you are, but if you are seeing items get "lost" then you probably aren't synchronizing properly. Instead of trying to do that, you could use a framework class that does it for you ...

... If you are always removing the next available (first) item (effectively a producer/consumer implementation) then you could use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation, This is guaranteed to be thread safe, and has the advantage of blocking the consumer until an item is available. An example is the `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

For non-blocking thread-safe queues you can look at [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Marking the list instance variable `volatile` has nothing to do with your list being synchronized for mutation methods like `add` or `removeFirst`. `volatile` is simply to do with ensuring that read/write for *that instance variable* is communicated correctly between, and ordered correctly within, threads. Note I said *that variable*, not the *contents of that variable* (see the [Java Tutorials > Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html))

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` is definitely not thread safe; you cannot use it safely with multiple threads.  It's not a question of "fast enough," it's a question of changes made by one thread being visible to other threads.  Marking it `volatile` doesn't help; that only affects references to the `LinkedList` being changed, not changes to the contents of the `LinkedList`.

Consider `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList is not thread safe, so yes, multiple threads accessing it simultaneously will lead to problems. Synchronizing critical sections can solve this, but as you are still having problems you probably made a mistake somewhere. Try wrapping it in a `Collections.synchronizedList()` to synchronize all method calls.

Answer (score 0):

`Linked list` is not thread safe , you can use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) if it fits your need,which seems possibly can.

As documentation says

> An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes. This queue
>   orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out). The head of the queue is
>   that element that has been on the queue the longest time. The tail of
>   the queue is that element that has been on the queue the shortest
>   time. New elements are inserted at the tail of the queue, and the
>   queue retrieval operations obtain elements at the head of the queue. A
>   ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an appropriate choice when many threads will
>   share access to a common collection. This queue does not permit null
>   elements.

Answer (score 0):

You increment your `inProcessCount` when `executedTask == null` which is obviously the opposite of what you want to do. So it’s no wonder that it will have inconsistent values.

But there are other issues as well. You call `notifyAll()` at several places but as long as there is no one calling `wait()` that has no use.

Note further that if you access an integer variable consistently from inside `synchronized` blocks only throughout the code, there is no need to make it an `AtomicInteger`. On the other hand, if you use it, e.g. because it will be accessed at other places without additional synchronization, you can move the code updating the `AtomicInteger` outside the `synchronized` block.

Also, a method which calls a method like `getAsyncQueue()` three times looks suspicious to a reader. Just call it once and remember the result in a local variable, then everone can be confident that it is the same reference on all three uses. Generally, you have to ensure that all code is using the same list, hence the appropriate modifier for the variable holding it is `final`, not `volatile`.